# Fetching a text page from a web browser using Tibco

Tags: tibco, tibco-topic

I'm trying to fetch a page from a web browser using Tibco tool.

For Example, URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant: en.wikipedia.org acts as the hostname, and after that comes in the file name I am opening.

Using Tibco tool(HTTP Palette), I try to fetch that page into my TIBCO, but when I run this it shows 4XX status code error.

Is there any way to fetch any page hosted in browser window to tibco without saving in my local machine?

Comment: I don't get the last sentence of the statement : "fetch any page hosted in browser window to bring to tibco without saving in between" ?

Comment: You could use file tools and parse an off-line version of an html file... but I assume you want to periodically watch for changes on the web site... In that case, you are using the right tool. You most probaly receive an 404 error because of a typo or network error. Is the target page public ? Can you share it ?

Comment: I have just reframed the question have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the `Send HTTP Request` activity like this:

### Configuration tab

[image: Configuration tab]

### Input tab

[image: Input tab]

Then run a test. The HTML content of the page will be returned in the `asciiContent` output field. Note that if you are sitting behind a proxy, you might need to configure it on the Configuration tab.

Comment: Hey thanks Nicolas Heitz you answer was a great help!!